# Updating Invoice Templates after editing in TFS

Tags: directory, crystal-reports, invoice

Once we have finished updating invoice templates in TFS, we need to input them into a folder within the network to ensure they are used during the bill run.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ensure that you have updated the invoices in TFS, and have saved them, and checked them in

Then go to the loaction on your Local Disk where the updated invoices will be saved to via TFS.  It will be somewhere like this;
C:\TFS\Billing Databases\Main\Invoice Templates

Open a new folder, and go to the location \LH-DELLSVR-02\Customer Data\Invoice Templates\New Invoices

Copy the updated invoice from your TFS location, and paste into the 'New Invoices' folder above

If the invoice is already there, it will ask you if you want to replace the previous version, click yes

If it's a totally new invoice for a new brand, it will copy directly